# X1 Carbon Gen 8 can't change charge thresholds via TLP 1.3.1

Tags: power-management, lenovo, thinkpad, acpi, tlp

I've got a new X1 gen8 with core i7 10510U CPU. I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 and tlp, were successfully changing charge levels up until this moment. I guess, I've installed some regular update and it doesn't work anymore :( When I try to do anything via `tlp` it tells `Error: battery charge thresholds not available.`

```
$ uname -r
5.11.0-27-generic
```

```
$ sudo tlp-stat -b
--- TLP 1.3.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ Battery Features: Charge Thresholds and Recalibrate
natacpi    = inactive (laptop not supported)
tpacpi-bat = inactive (laptop not supported)
tp-smapi   = inactive (laptop not supported)
```

One of those must be supported afaik... I've checked tlp faqs and found nothing about this issue. Appears, it is something about natacpi or something like that.

Comment: Lenovo’s battery management is handled completely within the UEFI. You can query the battery, but you cannot modify it … unless you use a special application that only runs in Windows (not Wine or a VM) 

Comment: @matigo the thing is I've been using `tlp` for a week or so, but it suddenly stopped working. It successfully allowed me to set any thresholds I want and it worked: the charging stopped at 80% or 60% - any threshold I set. But yesterday I discovered I cannot do that anymore. The only thing I did is 'apt get upgrade' and installing updates Software Updater found for Ubuntu, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the problem. I was messing up with thinkfan and broke `thinkpad_acpi` config, modprobe was unable to load it:

```
$ sudo modprobe thinkpad_acpi
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'thinkpad_acpi': Invalid argument
```

contents of `thinkpad_acpi.conf` were:

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/thinkpad_acpi.conf 
options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1
options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=7
```

leaving the only first line cured everything, `thinkpad_acpi` is loaded and `tlp` works via `natacpi`:

```
sudo tlp-stat -b
--- TLP 1.3.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ Battery Features: Charge Thresholds and Recalibrate
natacpi    = active (data, thresholds)
tpacpi-bat = active (recalibrate)
tp-smapi   = inactive (ThinkPad not supported)
```